# php dynamic image path

Tags: php, html, image

I have a header file which is used in many pages. header page has two images coded with relative path according to the index page(That's fine...!!! it works). Problem arises when header is called in different pages (which are in different tree structure) images does not display since header's image follow the same path instead of that path is suppose to be according to the page in which header is called. Please advise how to change the image path of header according to the page in which it is called.

Also i had somewhere read that relative eg.(images/logo.png) path is more wise than absolute eg.(http://example.com/images/logo.png) path from prospective of speed. What is this issue?

Comment: Just use absolute paths

Comment: Can you show some code. And I think using an absolute path is just as fast as a relative one.

Comment: that's because every time for loading image page look for DNS lookup in absolute path case.

Comment: <div class="row">                                       
      <div class="col-md-2" style="padding: 0px; margin-top: 10px;"> 
        <img src="images/logo.png">
 </div>

Comment: Where is the `images` directory? In the root of your project? And where is the header file?

Comment: images directory is in root. AND header slice is in root>common>pageslice>header.php

Comment: So if you do something like `src="<?php echo __DIR__ . '/../../images/logo.png';?>"` that should work I think.

Comment: @putvande that would give u local resource, which will not be showed when u visit the site

Comment: @user3651884 There is no DNS lookup (http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/4429/imgpathtypes.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to keep relative paths, perhaps you can build if-else scenarios using getcwd in PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

You can then specify that if it's for example longer than 5 chars (like home/) then you change to file path to

```
../img/file.gif
```

in any other case you just leave it like

```
img/file.gif
```

Hope this makes sense.